# How to avoid exit of Windows cmd terminal if called command executes `exit`?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, exit, exit-code

In a Windows cmd terminal, by cmd, I call command scripts (.cmd), but some of these does an `exit [code]` without the `/B`, whereby my Windows terminal is terminated.

How to avoid exit of Windows cmd terminal if called command executes `exit` without the `/B`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could invoke `scriptname.cmd` with `cmd /c`.  That way `exit` will exit your `cmd /c` invocation, rather than the ancestral console process.

**Test1.bat:**

```js
@echo off & setlocal

echo Exiting.
exit 0
```

**Test2.bat:**

```js
@echo off & setlocal

echo Invoking Test1.bat
cmd /c Test1.bat

echo Still running!
```

**Output of Test2.bat:**

> Invoking Test1.bat
>   Exiting.
>   Still running!

... and the console window remains open.

Comment: Thanks, the `cmd /c` handled this nicely, so I will skip using `call`.

Comment: If the Test1.bat sets environment variables that you want to keep, they will not be set unless the script runs inside the current shell. This is what `CALL` enables. You will lose that functionality. The .bat script should be corrected with `EXIT /B`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the exit code to 0? Something like this?

```
command && exit 0
```

I have not much experience with cmd commands but I believe that it should work.

Comment: The terminal still terminates with this construction.

Comment: Even if you create a bat file with that and invoke it before the exit?

Comment: What I need is a call that encapsulates the script, and `cmd /c` in the answer does the trick.